# rendering the yield statement depending on viewport?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following HTML Markup:

```
<div id="site-wrapper" class="show-for-large-only">
  <div id="site-canvas">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
</div>
```

For Mobile Devices i want an additional section like:

```
<div class="show-for-small-only">
    <%= yield %>
</div>
<div id="site-wrapper" class="show-for-large-only">
  <div id="site-canvas">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
</div>
```

With CSS i can hide the divs depending on the user's viewport.

Is there a way to avoid rendering the content of yield twice i.e. only to render the relevant div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server doesn't know about clients screen size and available viewport. Unless you specify it in the query string or separate ajax request I think it is impossible to determine.

In your place, I would make an additional ajax get request for desired mobile content.

EDIT:

In your controller, you can determine user-agent by http headers, using [request object](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html). I would write a helper for this. Save the result to an instance variable like `@is_mobile_agent` and in your view you would need an additional `if` statement before `yield`. Something like

```
yield if @is_mobile_agent
```